# Make Table ms access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am unable to create a table from the below query i get an type mismatch Error, the value is Text , the column is also text.

please find the below query:

```
DB.Execute " SELECT * INTO RESULTS FROM CCPA WHERE EMA_ADR LIKE & " * " & 
ME.SEARCHEMA.VALUE & " * ""
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
db.Execute "SELECT * INTO RESULTS FROM CCPA WHERE EMA_ADR LIKE '*" & Me.SEARCHEMA.Value & "*'"
```